# how to add data Labels to seaborn countplot / factorplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I use python3, seaborn countplot, my question :

1. how to add the count values for every bar? Show the label at the top of
   each bar?
2. how to have these bars in descending order?

I wrote this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.countplot(data_new['district'],data=data_new)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: For data labels, do you mean legend?

Answer (score 14):

I know it's an old question, but I guess there is a bit easier way of how to label a `seaborn.countplot` or `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` than in previous answer here (tested with matplotlib-3.4.2 and seaborn-0.11.1).

## With absolute values:

```
ax = sns.countplot(x=df['feature_name'],
                   order=df['feature_name'].value_counts(ascending=False).index);

abs_values = df['feature_name'].value_counts(ascending=False).values

ax.bar_label(container=ax.containers[0], labels=abs_values)
```

Example:
[image: pic1]

## With absolute & relative values:

```
ax = sns.countplot(x=df['feature_name'],
                   order=df['feature_name'].value_counts(ascending=False).index);
        
abs_values = df['feature_name'].value_counts(ascending=False)
rel_values = df['feature_name'].value_counts(ascending=False, normalize=True).values * 100
lbls = [f'{p[0]} ({p[1]:.0f}%)' for p in zip(abs_values, rel_values)]

ax.bar_label(container=ax.containers[0], labels=lbls)
```

Example:
[image: pic2]

Check these links:

1. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html
2. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/container_api.html

Comment: Can you show how to do both absolute and relative value with the presence of hue in a countplot?

Answer (score 12):

I used a simple example data I generated but you can replace the df name and column name to your data:

```
ax = sns.countplot(df["coltype"], 
                   order = df["coltype"].value_counts().index)

for p, label in zip(ax.patches, df["coltype"].value_counts().index):
    ax.annotate(label, (p.get_x()+0.375, p.get_height()+0.15))
```

This generates:
[image]

You will be likely to play around with the location a little bit to make it look nicer.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not make it clear.  I have  re-edit my question . Thank you very much for your help .

Answer (score 5):

If you capture the sns.countplot() return in a variable, you'll be able to set all matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot attibutes.

Do like:

```
c = sns.countplot(data_new['district'],data=data_new)
```

and then:

```
c.set_xlabel('Your X-axis label')
c.set_ylabel('Your Y-axis label')
```