# Customizing a seaborn countplot with additional categorical variable

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, bar-chart

I am following the guidance from there to create a bar chart similar to the last example:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html

however, I want to show only the survived =1 plot.

My data is very similar, and my chart looks like this (so I want to show only the right part of my chart with left =yes).
[image]

also, what values does the order parameter take? I wish I could sort them by count. It does not take desc or descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data=df[df['left']=='yes']` to just plot the right part.
To order by count, you can use `... .value_counts().index` for the `order=` parameter.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prob = np.random.rand(7) + 0.1
prob /= prob.sum()
df = pd.DataFrame({'department': np.random.choice(['helium', 'neon', 'argon', 'krypton', 'xenon', 'radon', 'oganesson'],
                                                  1000, p=prob),
                   'left': np.random.choice(['yes', 'no'], 1000)})
sns.set_style('white')
filter = df['left'] == 'yes'
g = sns.catplot(data=df[filter], kind='count', y='department', palette='mako_r',
            order=df[filter]['department'].value_counts(ascending=True).index)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fontsize=12)
    ax.margins(x=0.1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with kind='count' ordered by count]

Comment: cheers. very nice plot!

Comment: ok, I will. do you know how to add values to the end of the bars?

Comment: See second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044131/how-to-add-data-labels-to-seaborn-countplot-factorplot/49052124)

Comment: thanks. I was trying ax = grid.axes[0, 0]
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0]) and it did not work.

Comment: I added it to the example code.

Comment: you're a star. I have been trying like this, it did not work.
 for p, label in zip(g.patches, df[filter]['department'].value_counts().index):
    g.annotate(label, (p.get_y()+0.375, p.get_width()+0.15))

Comment: I know!  your example did not render labels with me - I am using Azure Databricks. their notebooks must be different from Jupyter.

Comment: all done! updated ML runtime to 9.1 from 7.3 and it works :)